# Can the spell Creation make magic items? (Official rulings only)

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

Is there an official ruling or rule that determines whether the spell *creation* can be used to create a magic item?

I'd like to know if any of the developers have posted a ruling about this, or whether there are other rules somewhere in the game that explicitly specify whether it's possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## The spell has no explicit restriction on creating magic items

The only thing *creation* specifies is that the object must be a "nonliving object of vegetable matter" or "mineral objects". The only examples given in the spell are generic item categories ("soft goods, rope, wood, or  something similar") and not anything that would limit things to mundane items explicitly either. So, technically, if you wanted to make a Rope of Mending, you could, since it is an item object made out of hemp (assuming you have seen it before).

An argument could be made that magic items are more than just their materials:

> Creating a magic item requires more than just time, effort, and materials. It is a long-term process that involves one or more adventures to track down rare materials and the lore needed to create the item. (XGE)<sup>1</sup>

However, that could easily be explained away by the fact that this is a spell that creates objects (temporarily) and being magic could easily be seen to bypass the "normal" requirements for the  creation of magic items (just as the spell already bypasses the normal crafting rules when it creates mundane objects).

#### It isn't intended to work that way

Jeremy Crawford has said in a [now-unofficial](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/with-the-2019-sage-advice-compendium-release-are-jeremy-crawfords-tweets-consi) [Tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/722199025751973888) that:

> The creation spell is not intended to create magic items.

Which is pretty clear. It is possible they simply meant to have the word "nonmagical" in there as it is in spells like *true polymorph*:

> You transform the creature into a different creature, the creature into a nonmagical object [...]

Though it is notable that this wording was only added to *true polymorph* after release with errata, so it seems that this oversight was made on multiple spells.<sup>2</sup>

While not exactly analogous (because *true polymorph* can create permanent objects and doesn't have material restrictions which itself is a huge step up in power), the fact that the 9th level *true polymorph* cannot create magic items is more indirect support for the fact that *creation*, a 5th level spell, should not be able to either.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1 - Note that this is from the optional rules in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*.</sup>

<sup>2 - Thanks @Medix2</sup>

<sup>3 - Thanks @KorvinStarmast</sup>

Comment: Should I leave up my answer which effectively says the exact same things?

Comment: Good point! I'll add a note there to that.

Comment: @Medix2 Yeah absolutely! Unless you really don't want to, it often helps to have answers that say the same thing in different ways. And mine came in after yours so I wouldn't want you to remove it on that account. And who knows, as time progresses we may think of different things that cause our answers  to diverge.

Comment: The `However this could easily be explained away...` paragraph confuses me slightly; are you saying that the use of "Creation" in this manner is plausable? The way the question is worded seems - to me - to make this paragraph say two different things at once.

Comment: You could potentially argue that the "rare materials" needed to create a magic item are not included on the list of materials and, on that basis, exclude magic items from the spell. (Assuming you're playing with XGtE rules.)

Comment: @TylerGubala My intention was to bring up a preemptive argument that might be made and why I think it doesn't really disprove the point. I'll think on it and try to make it a bit clearer. If you have any suggestions to that end please let me know :)

Comment: @RyanThompson I could see that as a potential venue, it's not clear to me that the materials are requisite to materials the magic item is actually made of though as opposed to, say, some sort of materials needed for the procedure to make it. And, of course, it is purposefully vague since this is just pitching the DM potential plot hooks and not interested in canonising the magic-item-making process. But it would certainly be a good way to explain in-universe why it might not work I think (assuming the DM chooses to rule that way).

Comment: I think that you could probably break that part up into two sentences instead of one longer sentence. Maybe something like: `while magic items could be ruled as out of scope of Creation because of the wording of the optional rule, a ruling is ultimately up to the DM. The spell, after all, bypasses the crafting requirements of mundane items.` Something to that effect would make it clearer for me, though that is purely my opinion.

Answer (score 11):

### It is not intended, but RAW *creation* can make magical items

As DerekStucki's answer shows, Jeremy Crawford's now unofficial ruling [here](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/722199025751973888) states:

> The creation spell is not intended to create magic items.

---

Using RAW, we do know that [spells do what they say](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637) and that *creation* creates a "nonliving object" or "mineral object". It does not specify that they need to be a nonmagical and without that clause nothing prevents you from creating magic items.

A spell which *does* explicitly forbid magic items is *true polymorph*; as [this Q/A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79518) explains there was an errata made to the spell so it now reads:

> You transform the creature into a different creature, the creature into a **nonmagical** object, or the object into a creature

What we know about other methods of crafting magic items is found in the Dungeon Master's Guide which states:

> The creation of a magic item is a lengthy, expensive task...

And in the "Crafting Magic Items" section in Xanathar's Guide to Everything which states:

> Creating a magic item requires more than just time, effort, and materials. It is a long-term process that involves one or more adventures to track down rare materials and the lore needed to create the item.

Note that these rules are for crafting as a downtime activity. Spells like *creation*, *fabricate*, and *true polymorph*, already bypass/ignore these rules when crafting mundane items (as there is not time requirement like in the dowtime activity rules).
This supports the idea that the *creation* spell bypasses/ignores these rules even when crafting magic items.

---

Note that allowing *creation* to create magical items would be rather out-of-line. This would be allowing a 5th level spell to do something a 9th level spell (*true polymorph*) cannot even do.
Even the incredibly powerful *wish* spell has one of the possible uses listed as:

> You create one object of up to 25,000 gp in value that **isn't a magic item**...

As @Rubiksmoose pointed out, magic items created by the *creation* spell are not permanent and so the comparison to *true polymorph* and *wish* is not a complete one. However, I still believe a 5th level spell creating temporary magic items would give the spell an incredible additional amount of utility and still result in an imbalance.

Strictly RAW, because the *creation* spell does not explicitly forbid the creation of magic items, you can create magic items, but this is not intended and I believe makes the spell overpowered.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast One point that makes the comparison not so apt is that TP can create permanent object whereas creation creates objects only temporarily. It doesn't make your point a bad one, but it does make the comparison a bit more difficult.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Yeah, if the item is a temporary magical effect, like the magic of Spiritual weapon, that does make it a bit squisiher as a concept.  The think is, if it is simply "magical" for the purposes of magical attacks versus immunities, that surely fits within the power of a 5th level spell, while if it "creates luck blade" that would seem to be out of balance.  +1 for the added analysis and insights.

Answer (score 10):

On April 18, 2016 Jeremy Crawford [tweeted](https://www.twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/722199025751973888):

> The creation spell is not intended to create magic items. #DnD

Comment: Had to change answer since Jeremy Crawford is no longer official.