# Can True Polymorph be used to create magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, polymorph

The *True Polymorph* spell allows you to turn a creature into an object and if you concentrate on it for 1 hour it becomes permanent. The relevant text follows:

> Choose one creature or non-magical object that you can see within
>   range. You transform [...] the
>   creature into an object [...].
>
> [...]
>
> **Creature into Object.** If you turn a creature into an object, it
>   transforms along with whatever it is wearing and carrying into that
>   form. The creature's statistics become those of the object...

Can polymorph be used to create magic items by polymorphing creatures into objects? Answers can have DM Fiat, but I would prefer a rules based answer or an answer by Jeremy Crawford or Sage Advice or some other 'official' source.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## You cannot create magic items with *true polymorph*

Per the 2018 [PHB errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf), *true polymorph* now explicitly disallows the transformation of creatures into magic items:

> You transform the creature into a different creature, the creature into a **nonmagical** object, or the object into a creature [..]

### Rules as Intended agrees

So Jeremy Crawford, lead rules developer of D&D, had ruled previously about the intent (which now agrees with the RAW above):

> ...whatever it is that you're targeting or transforming the person into [with true polymorph], when it comes to objects it should **always be a nonmagical object**. ([DRAGON TALK - 10/26/17 45:30](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/adam-bradford-todd-kenreck-dd-beyond))

he also indicated this previously [in a tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/910278122414653440?ref_src=twcamp%5Eshare%7Ctwsrc%5Em5%7Ctwgr%5Eemail%7Ctwcon%5E7046%7Ctwterm%5E1):

> True polymorph is not intended to make magic items.