# Can I use the True Polymorph spell to transform an object into a Mighty Servant of Leuk-o?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

If I have an irrelevant object that is Huge-sized, and I cast *true polymorph* on it, could I turn it into the stat block for the monster "[Mighty Servant of Leuk-o](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/mighty-servant-of-leuk-o)" and then control it?

Furthermore, if I cast it on myself or an ally, would it be functional for combat?
If so, would it need pilot(s)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at the description of the [*Mighty Servant of Leuk-o*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/magic-items#MightyServantofLeuko) magic item (TCoE, p. 131-133; bold for emphasis mine):

> the *Mighty Servant of Leuk-o* is a fantastically powerful, 10-foot-tall machine that turns into an animate construct **when piloted**.

The stats for the animate construct form are not the stats of a creature; they are the stats of the artifact+pilots together. (Note that the challenge rating is explicitly listed as "—", as the CR is meaningless without the pilots.) Since *true polymorph* can transform into "**an** object", or "**a** creature", you cannot transform your object into the animated form including the pilot creatures.

If instead you consider casting the spell on yourself or one of your allies and you aim to transform the target into the magic item known as *Mighty Servant of Leuk-o*, that won't work, since the updated text of the [*true polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) spell bars transformation into magical items. See this Q&A: [Can True Polymorph be used to create magic items?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79518/can-true-polymorph-be-used-to-create-magic-items)

Finally, let us imagine that we were to treat the stats of the animate form as those of a single creature. In that case, that single creature would have a proper CR. And that CR would be quite a bit higher than CR 9 (the limit of the object-to-creature option of *true polymorph*). According to the ["Monster Statistics by Challenge Rating"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#MonsterStatisticsbyChallengeRating) table in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (page 274), a CR 9 monster would have about AC 16, 200 hit points, attack bonus of +7, etc., all of which much lower than the stats of the Mighty Servant.

Answer (score 4):

Your DNDBeyond link gives this creature's CR as 0, but that appears to be a display bug.  Other sources, including ZwiQ's [link](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/magic-items#MightyServantofLeuko), give the CR as "--".  "--" is not less than or equal to 9, so you can't polymorph an object into this creature.

"--" also is not less than or equal to any other creature's CR, so you can't polymorph other creatures into this creature.